# angular.js input set to lowercase

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an email input form where a user inputs an email address. I need to ensure that the email address is lower-case.  What i'm struggling with is that i'm able to take an array or a string and convert it into lowercase or uppercase. However because this is asking for a user to input something i've been having trouble using those same techniques.

```
  %zip-input-md{ type: "email", "ng-model" => "vm.form.email", required: true, 'ng-maxlength' => 50, 'ng-disabled' => 'vm.form.validated_email' }
    Email address
```

I was initially thinking that the solution was `{{ lowercase_expression | lowercase}}` but that only works well for existing strings.

On the back end in the controller, the `vm.form.email` was defined in a submitForm method.

```
  vm.submitForm = (isValid) ->
    success = ->
      TokenService.post vm.form.email, vm.form.password
        .then tokenServiceSuccess, tokenServiceError
        .then tokenServiceFinally
      return
```

If anybody has any good ideas, i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the service `$filter` in your controller and then:

```
 vm.submitForm = (isValid) ->
    success = ->
      TokenService.post $filter('lowercase')(vm.form.email), vm.form.password
        .then tokenServiceSuccess, tokenServiceError
        .then tokenServiceFinally
      return
```